# What are some nice video cameras for recording talks?

Tags: video-camera

Desired Specifications:

- Auto-movement depending on the movement of the speaker (Auto-follow)
- HD resolution (720p)
- Should be compatible with live streaming
- Below $1000

Comment: How should it connect to computers? Should it be able to record, or just stream to a computer?

Comment: It should also be able to record.

Comment: How far is the speaker from the recording device?

Comment: @Andy About 10m (TEDx sized stage)